# Execute Python code with arguments inside YAML file

Tags: python, windows, docker, yaml, minikube

I have a python code where I am passing arguments to a function using CLICK package. I have dockerized this code and using the image inside a yaml file to deploy this inside minikube on my Windows machine. It worked fine without the arguments but with argument passing, it is giving field immutable error.

```
import click
@click.command()
@click.option(
    "--host_name",
    required=True,
    help="The host name of the db",
)
@click.option(
    "--port",
    required=True,
    help="Port where db is deployed",
)
def cli_function(host_name, port):
    CONNECTION = (
        " host="
        + host_name
        + " port="
        + port
........
    )
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli_function()
```

**YAML file**

```
spec:
      containers:
        - name: database
          image: docker image
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
          args:
            [
              "python3 /database_connection.py --host_name db-service --port 5432;",
            ]
```

**Complete Error**

```
The Job "timescaledbingestor" is invalid: spec.template: Invalid value: core.PodTemplateSpec{ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string{"app":"timescaledbingestor", "controller-uid":"407ae300-1455-4e41-bf88-ca7e01fe3d70", "job-name":"timescaledbingestor"}, Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:"", ManagedFields:[]v1.ManagedFieldsEntry(nil)}, Spec:core.PodSpec{Volumes:[]core.Volume(nil), InitContainers:[]core.Container(nil), Containers:[]core.Container{core.Container{Name:"timescaledbingestor-v1", Image:"628548651667.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/timescaledb-ingester", Command:[]string{"bash", "-c", "python3 data_sync.py --host_name timescaledb-service --port 5432 --user postgres --password password"}, Args:[]string(nil), WorkingDir:"", Ports:[]core.ContainerPort(nil), EnvFrom:[]core.EnvFromSource(nil), Env:[]core.EnvVar(nil), Resources:core.ResourceRequirements{Limits:core.ResourceList(nil), Requests:core.ResourceList(nil)}, VolumeMounts:[]core.VolumeMount(nil), VolumeDevices:[]core.VolumeDevice(nil), LivenessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), ReadinessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), StartupProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), Lifecycle:(*core.Lifecycle)(nil), TerminationMessagePath:"/dev/termination-log", TerminationMessagePolicy:"File", ImagePullPolicy:"Always", SecurityContext:(*core.SecurityContext)(nil), Stdin:false, StdinOnce:false, TTY:false}}, EphemeralContainers:[]core.EphemeralContainer(nil), RestartPolicy:"Never", TerminationGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(0xc00b865cb0), ActiveDeadlineSeconds:(*int64)(nil), DNSPolicy:"ClusterFirst", NodeSelector:map[string]string(nil), ServiceAccountName:"", AutomountServiceAccountToken:(*bool)(nil), NodeName:"", SecurityContext:(*core.PodSecurityContext)(0xc005cd7f00), ImagePullSecrets:[]core.LocalObjectReference(nil), Hostname:"", Subdomain:"", SetHostnameAsFQDN:(*bool)(nil), Affinity:(*core.Affinity)(nil), SchedulerName:"default-scheduler", Tolerations:[]core.Toleration(nil), HostAliases:[]core.HostAlias(nil), PriorityClassName:"", Priority:(*int32)(nil), PreemptionPolicy:(*core.PreemptionPolicy)(nil), DNSConfig:(*core.PodDNSConfig)(nil), ReadinessGates:[]core.PodReadinessGate(nil), RuntimeClassName:(*string)(nil), Overhead:core.ResourceList(nil), EnableServiceLinks:(*bool)(nil), TopologySpreadConstraints:[]core.TopologySpreadConstraint(nil)}}: field is immutable
```

Comment: `args` is a list and each element in your current single string should be a separate item exactly like for your `command` entry => `["python3", "database_connection.py", "--host_name", "db-service", "--port", "5432"]`. => https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

Comment: If you're seeing a "field is immutable" error, is the YAML file `kind: Pod`, and does the Pod already exist in the cluster?  Typically you'd use Deployments and not bare Pods, but if it is a Pod, you can't change most properties of it after it's been created and you need to manually delete it (a Deployment would do this for you).

Comment: Thank you David. This solved my problem. My kind was job and I couldn't edit it. I deleted the job manually and recreated it and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Author of the question made some changes in his Job. After the update he got a "field is immutable" error.

This is caused by the fact that `.spec.template` [field in Job is immutable](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/57c8024036938e40a48010299129b57b818c2a34/pkg/apis/batch/validation/validation.go#L158) and can not be updated.

**Solution**

Delete the old Job and create a new one with necessary changes.